# How to update subscribed value in html on change in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngonchanges

After clicking "Edit", "editStatus" function is called, then the value of "order.status" is changing. But the html view remains the same - displays the old status of order. It changes only after refreshing the page. How can I do the status show the updated variable after change?

html:

```
<div *ngIf="order">
    <p>Id:<b> {{ order._id }}</b></p>
    <p>Status:<b> {{ order.status }}</b></p>
</div>
<button (click)="editStatus(order)">Edit</button>
```

ts file:

```
private subscribe: Subscription;
  order: Order;
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe = this.route.params.pipe(
      map(({ id }) => id),
      switchMap((id: string) => this.orderService.getOrderById(id)))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.order = res;
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }

  editStatus(order) {
    const orderEdited = { order, status: 'order_canceled' };
    this.orderService.editStatus(orderEdited).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

order service:

```
private userOrdersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user-orders';

getOrderById(orderId): Observable<Order> {
  return this.http.get<Order>(`${this.userOrdersUrl}/${orderId}`);
}
editStatus(order) {
  return this.http.put<Order>(this.userOrdersUrl, order);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a student homework...

You do not assign the updated order to your variable. Change to the following:

```
res => {
    this.order = res;
},
```